# Performance of T-SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confused in the performance of the self joined tables in two different ways.  Query1 is:

```
SELECT  
    a1.attr_val AS attr_val1,
    a2.attr_val AS attr_val2,
    a3.attr_val AS attr_val3
FROM attr a1 
    LEFT JOIN attr a2 ON a1.ticket_id=a2.ticket_id AND a2.attr_type=2
    LEFT JOIN attr a3 ON a1.ticket_id=a3.ticket_id AND a3.attr_type=3
where a1.attr_type=1
```

Query2 is:

```
Select 
    a1.attr_val as attr_val1,
    a2.attr_val as attr_val2,
    a3.attr_val as attr_val3
from (select * from attr where attr_type=1) a1 
    left join (select * from attr where attr_type=2) a2 on a1.ticket_id=a2.ticket_id
    left join (select * from attr where attr_type=3) a3 on a1.ticket_id=a3.ticket_id
```

I thought when there is an index on ticket_id, Query1 is always faster than Query2 since Query1 can take advantage of this index while Query2 can not.  But in SQL Server 2016, I see Query2 is faster with 200k rows of data.

Is it before (select * from attr where attr_type=1) can narrow down the dataset first before join with other narrowed ones?

Why index can not help in this case?

Comment: Check the execution plans. A query is purely declarative, I e. Only describes the results you want. It doesn't say anything how the engine obtains those results.

Comment: Like @DaleK said, you need to check the execution plans, execution times are meaningless.

Comment: I did.  Query1 costs heavily in a sort operation. @Dale K.  Does index help sorting as well?

Comment: There you go then...

Comment: The rule of thumb for writing SQL, is to write your query in the clearest, most intuitive manner, and only worry about performance if/when it becomes an issue. There are a few exceptions such as avoiding cursors, avoiding functions in where clauses etc, but in general.

Comment: @DaleK, thanks!  Since Query2 has performance issue, I tried to improve it with Query1.  But it surprised me.

Comment: Well I find find query2 much less clear than query1 so maybe SQL server got confused as well. If you really want to know why SQL server made the decisions it made, the info will be in the execution plan, but you may have to take some time to learn how to read it.

Comment: Do the aforementioned. Also consider the column you're filtering on, attr_type for an index, mayb including ticket id. Working w/ Query plan, you may have to experiment. And finally, if numbers in QPlan don't add up, statistics might be stale.

Comment: It might help to attach some sort of query plan. Btw, do you need self join at all. Why not to: select ticket_id, max(case when attr1_type = 1 then attr_val end) AS attr1_val,max(case when attr1_type = 2 then attr_val end) AS attr2_val, max(case when attr1_type = 3 then attr_val end) AS attr3_val from yourtable group by ticket_id

Comment: Not just "It might help to attach some sort of query plan" - but this is required to answer your question.  Ideally the "Actual" execution plan XML for both versions as these contains information about things like wait stats, physical reads and per operator timings that are useful to know when evaluating query performances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought when there is an index on ticket_id, Query1 is always faster
> than Query2 since Query1 can take advantage of this index while Query2
> can not.

This is simply incorrect and easily disproved. By simply doing

```
create table attr(ticket_id int, 
  attr_type int,attr_val int, 
  primary key (ticket_id, attr_type))
```

and looking at the execution plans for both.

[image]

In both cases it has no option but to scan `attr` in order to get the rows where `attr_type=1` as there is no index on that. But is then able to do correlated index seeks on `ticket_id, attr_type` to get the rest of the joined values. Similarly if you add `OPTION (MERGE JOIN)` or  `OPTION (HASH JOIN)` or try reversing the order of the index key columns you still end up with execution plans that are the same with regards to how they access the base tables - query 2 has some extra compute scalars but they don't affect the index usage ([Fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/OmQdUrvP), [Fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZdVv_JyN)).

There is then no general rule that Query 1 or Query 2 are "better" than the other. Your query is a declarative expression of the desired results. SQL Server then figures out how to get the data from the tables that gets those desired results. The optimiser applies transformation rules and can rearrange things as long as the semantics stay the same.

In your case I would suspect one of the following explanations.

**(1) Transient Issues**

Query performance can vary from run to run dependent on things like concurrent activity on the system, synchronous statistics updates, amount of data that needs to be read from disc vs already in cache. It is unclear how repeatable this difference is.

**(2) Different Execution Plan**

The input query text is of course different, so the initial query trees produced from that text are different. Whilst the above plans show that SQL Server is capable of transforming both to the same final execution plan (ignoring the compute scalars) the different initial trees may still have some effect. It could affect the inputs to cardinality estimation for example (meaning a different strategy is selected as it appears cheaper with the different costings) or SQL Server could find a ["good enough"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137602/3690) plan before getting to trying the transformation rules required for both query texts to have the same plan. The optimiser does not exhaustively try every possible transformation in its armoury for every query.

Answer (score -2):

In general, Query1 should be faster when there is an index on ticket_id, because it can take advantage of that index to perform the joins more efficiently. Query2 is structured in a way that prevents SQL Server from fully utilizing the index, because each subquery is executed independently instead of being joined together. While Query2 may be faster in some specific cases, it's not a guarantee that it will always be faster.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this answer is vague - why are indexes utilized better in Query1 vs. Query2? What prevents Query2 from utilizing the index? What are the cases that make Query2 faster in some cases? Also it fails to address the problem mentioned many times in the comments to the original question - how do the query plans differ between Query1 and Query2. I think at the end of the day, until the OP provides some further detail (the query plans, or perhaps a test case to illustrate), it is difficult to do more than generalize and make guesses - but those are not really great answers.

Comment: I downvoted because as the comments say SQL is declarative. The optimiser is perfectly capable of using indexes whichever way the query is written. "Query2 is structured in a way that prevents SQL Server from fully utilizing the index, because each subquery is executed independently instead of being joined together" - this is simply incorrect and clearly based on ill informed guesswork about execution plans rather than experience looking at them

Comment: e,g. There is no particular difference in index use in any of these https://dbfiddle.uk/OmQdUrvP (or with alternative indexing of https://dbfiddle.uk/ZdVv_JyN)   - Query2 has some extra compute scalars but these won't affect any thing

Comment: @topsail sorry my company doesn't allow me to publish database information here.  The example I gave is a simplified example with the same code pattern.  The actual query is much more complicated.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the dbfiddle execution plan!  What really confusing me is why Query1 and Query2 are not much different in index usage.  "(select * from attr where attr_type=2) a2" in Query2 returns a dataset, which is probably as a temp table in database without index.  "attr2 a2" in Query1 has the index in the original table.  Does the database engine add index to the temp table by itself?

Comment: There is no temp table. "Query2 returns a dataset, which is probably as a temp table" is entirely the wrong way of thinking about it.  Your query is a **declarative** expression of the desired results. SQL Server then figures out how to get the data from the tables that gets those desired results (which in the db fiddle is the same way in both cases) - you are still thinking as if the queries were something procedural. This is not the case. The optimiser applies transformation rules and can rearrange things as long as the semantics stay the same

Comment: @MartinSmith that is the answer I am looking for.  I have this wrong concept for years.  I treated SQL as a procedure language.